# Looking to understand the iOS UIViewController lifecycle

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, lifecycle

Could you explain me the correct manner to manage the `UIViewController` lifecycle?

In particular, I would like to know how to use `Initialize`, `ViewDidLoad`, `ViewWillAppear`, `ViewDidAppear`, `ViewWillDisappear`, `ViewDidDisappear`, `ViewDidUnload` and `Dispose` methods in Mono Touch for a `UIViewController` class.

Comment: Is there some information or link for OSX ViewController and WindowController? Please share it.

Answer (score 437, accepted):

All these commands are called automatically at the appropriate times by iOS when you load/present/hide the view controller. It's important to note that these methods are attached to `UIViewController` and not to `UIView`s themselves. You won't get any of these features just using a `UIView`.

There's great documentation on Apple's site [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller). Putting in simply though:

- `ViewDidLoad` - Called when you create the class and load from xib. Great for initial setup and one-time-only work.
- `ViewWillAppear` - Called right before your view appears, good for hiding/showing fields or any operations that you want to happen every time before the view is visible. Because you might be going back and forth between views, this will be called every time your view is about to appear on the screen.
- `ViewDidAppear` - Called after the view appears - great place to start an animations or the loading of external data from an API.
- `ViewWillDisappear`/`DidDisappear` - Same idea as `ViewWillAppear`/`ViewDidAppear`.
- `ViewDidUnload`/`ViewDidDispose` - In Objective-C, this is where you do your clean-up and release of stuff, but this is handled automatically so not much you really need to do here.

Comment: This text is slightly misleading, as the ViewDidLoad should not be used for one-time-only work. It might be called several times if the view is unloaded due to low memory and then loaded again.

Comment: ViewDidLoad is not actually called when you create/initialize the view controller. It is called the first time you do anything view related with the view controller's view. Like add it as a subview, set the frame, etc. It is also called of course when loading from a nib.

Comment: ViewDidAppear - Called after the view appears - great place to start an animations or the loading of external data from an API. Why is it a good place to start loading data? Why not viewDidLoad?

Comment: what about loadView method, if it is called first time when a nib loaded in memory before viewDidLoad or not.

Comment: @chakrit this is a good point - viewDidAppear is a great place to refresh data(if you need to). I disagree about KVO, because it can cause undesirable refreshes on the views that are never actually viewed by a user.

Comment: will `ViewDidLoad` called when device orientation changes?

Comment: @astuter, No, `ViewDidLoad` will not be called when device orientation changes.

Comment: I don't agree with `ViewDidAppear ` part. I think ViewDidLoad is a good place if loading data only once, and ViewWillAppear is the place to refresh data.

Answer (score 418):

UPDATE: ViewDidUnload was deprecated in iOS 6, so updated the answer accordingly.

The UIViewController lifecycle is diagrammed here:

[image: A view controller's lifecycle, diagrammed]

The advantage of using Xamarin Native/Mono Touch, is that it uses the native APIs, and so it follows the same ViewController lifecycle as you would find in Apple's Documentation.

Comment: Where do viewWillLayoutSubviews and viewDidLayoutSubviews go on this  flowchart?

Comment: This diagram is inaccurate. viewDidUnload is deprecated since iOS6: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509102/viewdidunload-no-longer-called-in-ios6

Comment: This is indeed simply **wrong**.  Another example of a simply wrong answer on SO, as the years pass.  Computing is highly non-static.

Answer (score 231):

This is for latest iOS Versions(Modified with **Xcode 9.3, Swift 4.1**). Below are all the stages which makes the lifecycle of a `UIViewController` complete.

- `loadView()`
- `loadViewIfNeeded()`
- `viewDidLoad()`
- `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)`
- `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`
- `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`
- `viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)`
- `viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)`
- `viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool)`

Let me explain all those stages.

**1. `loadView`**

This event creates/loads the view that the controller manages. It can load from an associated nib file or an empty `UIView` if null was found.
This makes it a good place to create your views in code programmatically.

> This is where subclasses should create their custom view hierarchy if they aren't using a nib. 
>   Should never be called directly.
>   Only override this method when you programmatically create views and assign the root view to the `view` property
>   Don't call super method when you override
>   [loadView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview)

**2. `loadViewIfNeeded`**

If incase the view of current `viewController` has not been set yet then this method will load the view but remember, this is only available in iOS >=9.0. So if you are supporting iOS <9.0 then don't expect it to come into the picture.

> Loads the view controller's view if it has not already been set.

**3. `viewDidLoad`**

The `viewDidLoad` event is only called when the view is created and loaded into memory but the bounds for the view are not defined yet. This is a good place to initialise the objects that the view controller is going to use.

> Called after the view has been loaded. For view controllers created in code, this is after -loadView.
>   For view controllers unarchived from a nib, this is after the view is set.

**4. `viewWillAppear`**

This event notifies the `viewController` whenever the view appears on the screen. In this step the view has bounds that are defined but the orientation is not set.

> Called when the view is about to made visible. Default does nothing.

**5. `viewWillLayoutSubviews`**

This is the first step in the lifecycle where the bounds are finalised. If you are not using constraints or Auto Layout you probably want to update the subviews here. This is only available in iOS >=5.0. So if you are supporting iOS <5.0 then don't expect it to come into the picture.

> Called just before the view controller's view's layoutSubviews method is invoked.
>   Subclasses can implement as necessary. The default is a nop.

**6. `viewDidLayoutSubviews`**

This event notifies the view controller that the subviews have been setup. It is a good place to make any changes to the subviews after they have been set. This is only available in iOS >=5.0. So if you are supporting iOS <5.0 then don't expect it to come into the picture.

> Called just after the view controller's view's layoutSubviews method is invoked.
>   Subclasses can implement as necessary. The default is a nop.

**7. `viewDidAppear`**

The `viewDidAppear` event fires after the view is presented on the screen. Which makes it a good place to get data from a backend service or database.

> Called when the view has been fully transitioned onto the screen.
>   Default does nothing

**8. `viewWillDisappear`**

The `viewWillDisappear` event fires when the view of presented `viewController` is about to disappear, dismiss, cover or hide behind other `viewController`. This is a good place where you can restrict your network calls, invalidate timer or release objects which is bound to that `viewController`.

> Called when the view is dismissed, covered or otherwise hidden.

**9. `viewDidDisappear`**

This is the last step of the lifecycle that anyone can address as this event fires just after the view of presented `viewController` has been disappeared, dismissed, covered or hidden.

> Called after the view was dismissed, covered or otherwise hidden. 
>   Default does nothing

Now as per **Apple** when you are implementing this methods you should remember to call `super` implementation of that specific method.

> If you subclass UIViewController, you must call the super implementation of this method, even if you aren't using a NIB.  (As a convenience, the default init method will do this for you, and specify nil for both of this methods arguments.) In the specified NIB, the File's Owner proxy should have its class set to your view controller subclass, with the view outlet connected to the main view. If you invoke this method with a nil nib name, then this class' `-loadView` method will attempt to load a NIB whose name is the same as your view controller's class. If no such NIB in fact exists then you must either call `-setView:` before `-view` is invoked, or override the `-loadView` method to set up your views programatically.

Hope this helped.
Thanks.

**UPDATE**  -  As @ThomasW pointed inside comment `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will also be called at other times when subviews of the main view are loaded, for example when cells of a table view or collection view are loaded.

**UPDATE**  - As @Maria pointed inside comment, description of `loadView` was updated

Comment: `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will also be called at other times when subviews of the main view are loaded, for example when cells of a table view or collection view are loaded.

Comment: There is a slight misleading in this answer: loadView() is always called, it just shouldn't be overridden when view for controller created in IB.

Comment: @Maria Please go ahead and edit the answer if you think it can be improved. Thanks.

Comment: Default does nothing is wrong for `viewWillAppear` `viewDidAppear` `viewDidDisappear`. You must call super at some point.

Answer (score 51):

**iOS 10,11** ***(Swift 3.1,Swift 4.0)***

According to `UIViewController` in `UIKit` developers,

**1. loadView()**

This is where subclasses should create their custom view hierarchy if they aren't using a [nib](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/NibFile.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH34-SW1). Should never be called directly.

**2. loadViewIfNeeded()**

Loads the view controller's view if it has not already been set.

**3. viewDidLoad()**

Called after the view has been loaded. For view controllers created in code, this is after -loadView. For view controllers unarchived from a nib, this is after the view is set.

**4. viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)**

Called when the view is about to made visible. Default does nothing

**5. viewWillLayoutSubviews()**

Called just before the view controller's view's layoutSubviews method is invoked. Subclasses can implement as necessary. Default does nothing.

**6. viewDidLayoutSubviews()**

Called just after the view controller's view's layoutSubviews method is invoked. Subclasses can implement as necessary. Default does nothing.

**7. viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)**

Called when the view has been fully transitioned onto the screen. Default does nothing

**8. viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)**

Called when the view is dismissed, covered or otherwise hidden. Default does nothing

**9. viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool**)

Called after the view was dismissed, covered or otherwise hidden. Default does nothing

**10. viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)**

Called when the view is Transitioning.

**11. willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?)**

**12. didMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?)**

These two methods are public for container subclasses to call when transitioning between child controllers. If they are overridden, the overrides should ensure to call the super.

The parent argument in both of these methods is nil when a child is being removed from its parent; otherwise it is equal to the new parent view controller.

**13. didReceiveMemoryWarning()**

Called when the parent application receives a memory warning. On iOS 6.0 it will no longer clear the view by default.

Comment: It really really sux that stackoverflow won't purge all the wrong and incomplete answers from this entire thread.  Your answer seems complete as far as method calls go, so I'm going to assume yours is correct and work with that.

Comment: What is a `nib` as mentioned under `loadView`?

Comment: @LogicsaurusRex I agree. In the same way that SO marks questions as duplicates or protected, I think it should be able to mark answers as *outdated* or *obsolete*

Comment: Point 5 above is wrong. `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` is called before the ViewController's view object invokes its `layoutSubviews()` method

Answer (score 28):

As of iOS 6 and onward. The new diagram is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Call that view "A". Consider a second view "B" that is appearing while "A" disappears. Is "B.viewWillAppear" before or after "A.viewDidDisappear"?  And are there any situations where the order of those two changes?

Comment: Seems like new view's (B) willApear will be called before the disAppears. For second question. Need some time to look into it.

Answer (score 22):

Let's concentrate on methods, which are responsible for the [UIViewController's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/) lifecycle:

- **Creation:**

  `- (void)init`

  `- (void)initWithNibName:`
- **View creation:**

  `- (BOOL)isViewLoaded`

  `- (void)loadView`

  `- (void)viewDidLoad`

  `- (UIView *)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`

  `- (UIView *)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder`
- **Handling of view state changing:**

  `- (void)viewDidLoad`

  `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`

  `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`

  `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated`

  `- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated`

  `- (void)viewDidUnload`
- **Memory warning handling:**

  `- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning`
- **Deallocation**

  `- (void)viewDidUnload`

  `- (void)dealloc`

[image: UIViewController's lifecycle diagram]

For more information please take a look on [UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/).

Answer (score 20):

The methods `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` aren't mentioned in the diagrams, but these are called between `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`.  They can be called multiple times.

Comment: They will also be called at other times when subviews of the main view are loaded, for example when cells of a table view or collection view are loaded.

Answer (score 16):

Haider's answer is correct for pre-iOS 6.  However, as of iOS 6 viewDidUnload and viewWillUnload are never called.  The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidUnload) state: "Views are no longer purged under low-memory conditions and so this method is never called."

Comment: I tried putting a breakpoint in ViewWillDisappear, ViewDidDisappear, Dispose. But none of them were getting invoked when I navigated with PresentViewController() method. What could be the reason ?

Comment: The link doesn't work ...  So what does the OS do under low memory?

Comment: Saves them to disk?

Answer (score 16):

There's a lot of outdated and incomplete information here. For **iOS 6 and newer** only:

1. `loadView`<sup>[a]</sup>
2. `viewDidLoad`<sup>[a]</sup>
3. `viewWillAppear`
4. `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is the first time bounds are finalized
5. `viewDidLayoutSubviews`
6. `viewDidAppear`
7. `*` `viewWillLayoutSubviews`<sup>[b]</sup>
8. `*` `viewDidLayoutSubviews`<sup>[b]</sup>

---

<sub>**Footnotes:**</sub>

<sub>(a) - If you manually nil out your view during `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, `loadView` and `viewDidLoad` will be called again. That is, by default `loadView` and `viewDidLoad` only gets called once per view controller instance.</sub>

<sub>(b) May be called an additional **0** or more times.</sub>

Comment: `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will also be called at other times when subviews of the main view are loaded, for example when cells of a table view or collection view are loaded.

Comment: @ThomasW But not before `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 11):

Explaining State Transitions in the official doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html

This image shows the valid state transitions between various view ‘will’ and ‘did’ callback methods

Valid State Transitions:

[image]
<sup>Taken from: [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Art/UIViewController Class Reference_2x.png](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Art/UIViewController%20Class%20Reference_2x.png)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As per [Apple's doc — Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)
 — Work with View Controllers — Understand the View Controller Lifecycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1)

> `viewDidLoad()`—Called when the view controller’s content view (the top of its view hierarchy) is created and loaded from a storyboard.
>   …
>   Use this method to perform any additional setup required by your view controller.
>
> `viewWillAppear()`—Called just before the view controller’s content view is added to the app’s view hierarchy. Use this method to trigger any operations that need to occur before the content view is presented onscreen
>
> `viewDidAppear()`—Called just after the view controller’s content view has been added to the app’s view hierarchy. Use this method to trigger any operations that need to occur as soon as the view is presented onscreen, such as fetching data or showing an animation.
>
> `viewWillDisappear()`—Called just before the view controller’s content view is removed from the app’s view hierarchy. Use this method to perform cleanup tasks like committing changes or resigning the first responder status.
>
> `viewDidDisappear()`—Called just after the view controller’s content view has been removed from the app’s view hierarchy. Use this method to perform additional teardown activities.