# UINavigationController FUNKY

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am currently using this guide such that I can replace the root controller with another view controller.
http://starterstep.wordpress.com/2009/03/05/changing-a-uinavigationcontroller%E2%80%99s-root-view-controller/

Currently, I have gotten that down on my app.

Consider the following scenario, View A (root) -> View B

On View B, there is a boolean value called firstLine (set to YES in viewDidLoad) which is used for a parsing algorithm. The algorithm works perfectly when we go into the view on the first time. (view A -> view B)

However, this new scenario breaks my parsing algorithm,

view A -> view B (pressed back) -> view A -> view B ( breaks )

This is where the boolean value (firstLine) is alternating weirdly when it is suppose to be set to YES when we first enter into the view. I am starting to believe that the first view B is still running on the background; thus, I tried popViewController but that didn't really work. It gave me a black screen, which is obviously what I don't want.

Any ideas?

**EDIT: SOLVED**

Turns out I was using an NSTimer and that kept on going off on its own. Therefore, I had to invalidate it when I left the view.

Comment: Im not qute sure i  understand you. do you want firstline = YES when you get back into View A? You should set the Value in ViewWillApear or viewDidAppear, then.

Comment: this boolean value is set in view B at viewDidLoad

I am using this boolean value in view B for parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the answers to this question [Looking to understand the iOS UIViewController lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle)
This will help you in determining when to set your flag in your view and what happens going from one UIView to another.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:myPreparedNewVCsStack 
animated:YES];
```

You can filter, move and replace any view controllers:

```
NSMutableArray *tempStack = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];

[tempStack filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"class != %@", [AViewController class]]]; // the predicate can be even @"firstEnter == YES"
```

Your last view controller in new stack will be the top one!