# ViewDidLoad call only one time in time of navigation

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I have viewcontroller. I have created its object in appdelegate.m file as I want to use that viewcontroller in poptoviewcontroller method. Now once I have created its object in appdelegate file and when I am pushing that viewcontroller it is calling viewdidload only 1 times. But from second time it is not calling viewdidload. I have some  component which i want to load each and every time that controller load. What to do?? Is there any other way to use viewcontroller in popToViewController method without creating its object in appdelegate.m file

I have 4 viewcontroller A,B,C,D.
I am navigating from A to B. And I have some component in B which I am loading in viewdidLoad. Now From A to B flow I am getting value from server of component. And displaying in B. Now if user want to change value then he will redirect to C from B to change B component value. And also some times he will redirect to D and from D I am poping to B with B component value. Now If i will write my B code in viewwillappear then When I will return from C to B it will load value which I got at the time of navigation from A to B.

Comment: it happen because one instance of the object is loaded only into the memory once. for improving your skills of the view-controllers and their lifecycle in iOS, please visit: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` (this last one is called after the first). ViewDidLoad is only called when the ViewController is constructed. Then, since you let it live in the navigation stack it isn't called anymore.

For more information follow this [thread on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle).

**EDIT**

With your edit the whole question becomes a different one. If you want a delegate to be called every time you will show your ViewController `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` is the answer.

It seems to me that you are over complicating things. From what I understand you are changing B in your AppDelegate? If so I can't see any problem with B having a previous state when you came from C and update your state in `viewWillAppear`. If you have some kind of pointer in the AppDelegate to B and you change it, then the viewWillAppear shouldn't have any issue.

You can have several solutions for your problem, and it all depends on your specific case but I would suggest that you separate the model better. You could create a singleton that holds B data and in the `viewWillAppear` you can get that data and display it. Then C and D only perform changes on that singleton.

Comment: from navigated viewcontroller I can navigate to another viewcontroller to change value of component. So if i use viewwillappear then it will not hold my vlaue.

Comment: This is true, unless your `UIViewController` gets unloaded because of memory constrains. On that case, `viewDidLoad` will be called again.

Comment: @vivek if you have a specific problem you need to be more specific in your questions as well. Maybe show us an example?

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida See my explanation.

Comment: @vivek edited my answer but this is kinda another question you are doing. This has to do with the architecture of your app, not with the viewController life cycle. You are misleading people (and google) with your question.

Comment: means???...I set value of component of B via array which is intialize in A. I have written that code in viewwillappear. So when I will come from C it will agian load same value from that array...and what you said about singleton? can you put more light on it

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` Method only called on initialisation of class, If you have some task to do again and again whenever view appears on screen than use 
`viewWillAppear` 
or 
`viewDidAppear` 
Method.