# Camera Roll keeps appearing after selecting image

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

So I've had a few different problems with this app, its my first app and never coded before, first was I couldn't get my button to open a "secondviewcontroller" to display my image, thinks i fixed that now, now when my button loads my "secondviewcontroller" it opens the camera roll I select an image and then it closes and reopens the camera roll to reselect another image.

**This is my FirstViewController.h - its calledBESPOKEViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

@interface BESPOKEViewController : UIViewController
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property BOOL newMedia;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
- (void)useCamera:(id)sender;
- (void)useCameraRoll:(id)sender;

@end
```

**BESPOKEViewController.m**

```
#import "BESPOKEViewController.h"


@interface BESPOKEViewController ()

@end

@implementation BESPOKEViewController





- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (IBAction) useCamera:(id)sender
{
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
    [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType =
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                       animated:YES completion:nil];
    _newMedia = YES;
}
}
- (IBAction) useCameraRoll:(id)sender{}





@end
```

**This is my SecondViewController.h - its called secondpage.h**

```
@interface secondpage : UIViewController
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@end
```

**secondpage.m**

```
#import "secondpage.h"

@interface secondpage ()

@end

  @implementation secondpage

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
// method call
[self openGallery];

}

-(void) openGallery {
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;

imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];



imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;



imagePicker.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:NO completion:^{



}];

}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)imagePicker    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

{

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

}];
// change the name of imageview here your way
self.imageView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

}


- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

updated to all code just not source from storyboard, would 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: was adding it as you replied :)

Comment: @C.Wetherell you want to open photo library when navigate to secondViewController select an image and dismiss?

Comment: that's correct i also want to display the image in the secondViewController

Comment: btw, you've got an extra { at the end of your source example (was there before I reformatted it) not sure if it's just a copy-paste error?

Comment: its not there in my actual code, must just be a copy paste error lol thank you

Comment: @C.Wetherell paste your complete code so that someone can guide you better

Comment: @C.Wetherell you should accept the below answer then by clicking on that tick sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're calling the `[self openGallery];` method from `viewDidAppear`, `openGallery` will get called every time the view appears.

What is happening is:

SecondPage loads and then appears -> GalleryView Displayed -> Image selected -> Gallery view disappears -> SecondPage appears

When you dismiss the gallery view, `viewDidAppear` is called on SecondPage again, which is why you get a never ending loop.

This is part of the viewController lifecycle. Because only one viewController is being presented at a time, even though SecondPage was the view that was presenting the picker, it calls `viewDidAppear` again.

So what you need to do is call the `openGallery` method when the ViewController is first loaded, not every time it's displayed.

You could try putting the `[self openGallery]` call in `viewDidLoad`, or else have some logic to determine whether you want the gallery to be displayed in `viewDidAppear` or not.

This question also has a good answer to understand the viewController life-cycle: [Looking to understand the iOS UIViewController lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this method

//this function will open your photolibrary

```
-(void) openGallery {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;

    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];



    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;



    imagePicker.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:^{



    }];

}
```

//you can adjust your image to different modes + library will be dismissed when image is selected

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    }];
    self.imgView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

}
```

// to cancel without selecting

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    }
```

and finally just call the function in `viewWillAppear`

```
[self openGallery];
```

plus add

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

in your `viewWillAppear` method

Comment: i added this code but it still just keeps reopening the imagepicker

Comment: @C.Wetherell check the updated code, you can put your own condition to check the photo gallery available etc

Comment: done all this, im now getting "use of undeclared identifier'openGallery' think ive forgot to do something just cant figure out what *tired* :(  thank you so much for your help

Comment: man you are doing it wrong way they all are seperate methods wait a sec

Comment: @C.Wetherell http://pastie.org/9127906 check this replace your code and read the answer care fully again and also the comments in this paste

Comment: ok, sorry about that i thought it all had to be in my viewDidAppear.. i have changed accordingly now but its still doing the same thing, when i click my button to goto the new viewcontroller, it opens the gallery i select an image and then it dismisses the gallery to the new viewcontroller but soon as that happens it then opens Gallery again - im so sorry for this :(

i have updated the code in my questions, I'm not getting errors now thankfully :)