# camera / photo album doesn't reload on ios after the tab has been clicked once

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I have an ios app that has a tab button for opening camera and another button for opening photo album. They open the first time just fine, but if you **cancel** or go to another tab, camera and photo album won't open the second time.

As an example, here's the photo album view controller. Only thing I changed is `viewDidLoad` method and adding `openPhotoAlbum` method. I used storyboard to add tabs.

## PhotoAlbumViewController.m

```c
#import "PhotoAlbumViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface PhotoAlbumViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) AppDelegate *appDelegate;

@end

@implementation PhotoAlbumViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self openPhotoAlbum];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

- (IBAction)openPhotoAlbum
{
    UIImagePickerController *albumPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    albumPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    albumPicker.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:albumPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

step 1: i click Album

[image]

step 2: photo album shows up the first time

[image]

step 3: cancel

step 4: photo album doesn't show up

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a tab bar controller managing  your hierarchy,  your view controller will get created the first time you select them.  When they are created, `viewDidLoad` will be called.

Once they are created, the will hang around and will re-appear when you select their tab again.

A better choice would be to use `viewWillAppear` which is called both on the first creation (after viewDidLoad) and on every subsequent appearance of the `UIViewController`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
//called only on initial creation and appearance
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
//called on every appearance
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self openPhotoAlbum];
}
```

[Here is a good SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12608364/793607) for understanding the lifecycle of UIViewController