# ViewDidLoad when returning to higher level UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've built a large tableview and have found that if I go down a step then click 'back' that the viewdidload function is not called. I need to run a function every time this layer of the UITableView is viewed. Is there a function that will run regardless of whether the view has been previously loaded?

Comment: How about `viewWillAppear:`?

Comment: Here you can read about [lifecycle of UIViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

viewDidLoad is called once and only once when the view gets loaded. In your situitation, viewWillAppear might not work as well because it's only called only if the view gets loaded on the canvas. You might need to pass a delegate to the table view controller or view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}
```