# Executing Event on Unwind Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

I'm not sure if I explained this correctly in my question, so I'll explain it here. Please excuse my iOS illiteracy, complete newbie here.

The master view controller is a `UITableViewController` that holds a list of items. So, each cell contains an item. This list is populated from a Core Data model.

If I want to add an item, there's an Add button that takes me to a different view controller that has a text field. I write the item name in the text field, press  the Done button and it adds it to Core Data, **and unwinds back to the UITableViewController**.

I want the table view to reload its data as soon as the unwind happens, so the user sees that his item has been entered into the list. I have to use a refresh control in order for the table to reload its data.

Is there a method whose code runs once the part written in bold happens?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can reload your table view data in the `viewWillAppear` method of the `UITableViewController`, which is called every time your view appears on screen. You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle) for more details on the view controller lifecycle.

Comment: `reloadData` is a poor way to update a table as it gives the user no idea of what has changed.  Use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` which gives the user visual feedback with animation.