# A method in the parent UIViewController that will be called when a modal UIViewController is about to display or dismissed

Tags: swift3, uiviewcontroller

So as the title say, I'm looking for a method that will be called when a "modal" UIViewController is about to be displayed -- so I can remove any attached observers -- then a method when the presented "modal" UIViewController is dismissed -- so I can reattach the observers --

In android when dialog is displayed the "fragment's onPause" is called then the "fragment's onResume" is called when the dialog is dismissed. I'm looking for something like that.

I know this can be done with the use of the delegate but If there's a already existing one that I'm not aware of please let me know.

Comment: Take a look at this - [iOS - Android Life Cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969032/what-the-equivalent-of-activity-life-cycle-in-ios)

Comment: @Chris thanks for the quick response, I already tried that and viewWillDisappear is not called when a modal is displayed over.