# Orientation Bug - Stuck in landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got an iPhone app with a `UIViewController` as the first controller. In it, I've got the standard methods that force it to be landscape (see below).

I've also got a second view that I show as a modal in the viewWillAppear -- it's meant as a splash screen while I pull down some content from the 'net.

The problem happens when I physically rotate my device into landscape mode and start the app. The modal shows (in portrait), but when it gets dismissed a few seconds later, the main view is displayed in landscape.

On the other hand, if I comment out the code for the modal and launch the app in landscape, the main view shows up in portrait as it should.

Any suggestions on how I can keep the main view in portrait mode when the app is launched from landscape?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   // Show the loading splash screen until the webview has completed
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sgImageModal" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"sgImageModal"]) {     
       splashScreen.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;        
   }
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [self viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

**Update 1**

As per suggestions, I've moved the logic to display the modal into viewDidAppear and viewDidLoad. I also changed shouldAutorotate to return YES. Neither had the desired impact.

Answer (score 0):

You can't present a modal view controller until the current view controller has finished it's loading, or finished it's transition. 90% of the time, this means you have to present a modal view controller in `viewDidAppear:` as opposed to `viewWillAppear:`. The problem is, that when code is executed in `viewWillAppear:`, the view may not be finished it's setup (including figuring out which orientation to present itself in).

[**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570363/1645229) is a handy answer by Jacob Knobel which explains exactly when each view lifecycle method is called.

Therefore, if you want the splash screen to appear right away, make it present **without animation**, presenting it from `viewDidAppear:`. Upon launching your application your modal should appear right away.

**Edit** - Have you tried returning `YES` from `shouldAutorotate`? You've specified your supported interface orientations, and told it that it should automatically rotate if the orientation is portrait, however you've told it that it shouldn't automatically rotate?

Comment: This is partly true. You can actually have a view controller present another from `viewDidLoad`. In that case, the `viewWill|DidAppear` methods of the first are not called until the second is dismissed.

Comment: You can, but this really isn't advised and can yield unpredictable results. At runtime, the `viewDidLoad` method may be called again, for example if the runtime needs to release/reload a controller in the case of a memory warning. In this case, your view controller would be presented again, which isn't ideal!

Comment: A quick change to my code moving this to viewDidAppear still causes the main view to show up in landscape.

Comment: @JohnRogers `viewDidUnload` hasn't been used since iOS 5.

Comment: True. You get the idea. Don't use `viewDidLoad` to present view controllers, was my intended takeaway from the comment.

Comment: @JohnRogers Thanks for the suggestion - I guess I didn't understand what shouldAutorotate did. In any case, changing to YES didn't help in this situation.