# Method in viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad didn't loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewdidload, viewwillappear

I have created a method to check the status of a server in my viewcontroller, I need to check this, everytime I will open the app.

I call `[self checkStatus];` from viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad, but when I open the app, by clicking home button, and I try to open the app again (clicking the app icon in applications) this method is not called. I have a NSLog to view when it is launched or not.

I'm frustrated. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can react to app changes using `NotificationCenter`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doSomething:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

BTW: don't forget to `removeObserver` when you don't need it!

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

You can also use `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` etc, depending what do you need.

You should read about app lifecycle on Apple Developer pages :). Read:

- [AppleDeveloperLink](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW1) Especially section: **"Execution States for Apps"** to know more about app lifecycle.
- [StackOverflowLink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570363/849616) to know more about view lifecycle.

Comment: Where I need to put this? In the ViewController? On the viewWillAppear? Sorry for my noob knowledge.

Comment: @Victor_J_Martin You should put `addObserver` in your viewController eg in `viewDidLoad`, and `removeObserver` in `dealloc` method.

Comment: I know, I'm trying to debug my app to view the results, but when the app goes to background the xcode log stops listen, so I don't know at this moment if this works or not. When I see it, I accept the answer. I'm slow, sorry.

Comment: @Victor_J_Martin I don't understand. You've asked how to get information if app is going to/from the background (and you should receive it now when you come back from HomeScreen). If you want to see logs in the background it's not relevant to the question you've asked.. You should set proper backgroundMode in this case.

Comment: I was working to know if your answer solves my problem. I have not accepted the answer because I could not see the result by other issues. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`iOS` is not calling those methods again, but the delegate methods in the `AppDelegate`. You have to propagate the message to your controllers then.

I hope this will help you: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/

Comment: Then, where I need to call the method [self checkStatus] to be opened everytime app appears?

Comment: You have to catch the action in the `AppDelegate` and then you must have a reference to the controller. Or you can use `NSNotification` to send the message to the other components