# PopToRootViewController does not update collectionview when user logs in

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I am making an simple chatting app and I want to update to the latest messages when the user logs in. Right now the collection view cells do not update to the newest messages even though i call `self.collectionView.reloadData()` in `ViewDidAppear`. 
In my `loginViewController` I have a function where i pop to the root view controller(inbox), and I don't know how I can update the data before it pops to the inbox. As i said I am calling `self.collectionView.reloadData()` in the `viewDidAppear` and it does not update. When I run on simulator I have to go to the compose screen and go back to inbox before it updates the messages.

```
func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController, didSignUpUser user: PFUser) {

  dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

Does anyone know a fix?

Comment: Showing the messages

Comment: you should first know about view life cycle. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle . you should call ViewWillApeear method if you want to load that view again.

Comment: were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

As your title suggests "`PopToRootViewController`" : I guess the code which will fetch recent messages is within `viewDidLoad()`. And `viewDidLoad()`is  not called during `PopToRootViewController`.

Move the code which fetches recent messages into to the `viewWillAppear()` and see what happens.