# Why is my UIView moving out of place inside UIScrollView when scrolled?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

So I made a test project in Xcode to see how I can use a `UITextField` and `UILabel`s, which are subviews of a `UIView`. And the `UIView` is a subview of a `UIScrollView`. So after adding the views and the code in `viewDidAppear` and when I scroll down the `UIView` moves out of place.

Here is a video of the problem: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5j_BdtRjSyARWp3cGQ1dkMzMFk/view?usp=sharing

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    scrollView.contentSize.height = 1000

    scrollView.contentSize.width = view.frame.width

    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false

    scrollView.contentOffset.x = -8

    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.25)
    scrollViewChildView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.25)
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to layout your views after it were positioned with autolayout system, so after you force it to **layoutSubviews** (with dragging to bottom) your content moves as presumed with specified offset that you are set to it (x = -8 and y = 0). For more information, referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle)