# Using UIAlertController in Xcode 8 with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I am trying to show a `UIAlertController` every time the user start the app.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My alert" message:@"This should be come when the app start" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *yesButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"YES" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];

    [alert addAction:yesButton];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But this is not working. I run the app in Xcode simulator. The app runs but no alertview is showing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that viewcontroller for that viewDidLoad - is actually on screen?

Comment: didn't really clear about your question. as i am new in ios developemnt. there is only one viewController and one storyboard in my app. @PavelGatilov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening the `UIAlertController` in the `viewDidAppear:` delegate instead. Alternatively, you could show it as part of your `AppDelegate` method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to make it more view-controller independent.

Comment: it worked .  i just copy and paste the code for alertview in viewDidAppear: and problem solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you are newbie in iOS so you must spend your little time to understand all the functions of `appdelegate` class and after that [`viewController` life cycle method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570363/4003548) so you will know about the startup behavior of application this will solve your problem like you shared above :)

**App delegate methods:**

- **application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** —This method allows you to perform any final initialization before your app is displayed to the user.
- **application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** —This method is your app’s first chance to execute code at launch time.
- **applicationDidBecomeActive:** —Lets your app know that it is about to become the foreground app. Use this method for any last minute preparation.
- **applicationWillResignActive:** —Lets you know that your app is transitioning away from being the foreground app. Use this method to put your app into a quiescent state.
- **applicationDidEnterBackground:** —Lets you know that your app is now running in the background and may be suspended at any time.
- **applicationWillEnterForeground:** —Lets you know that your app is moving out of the background and back into the foreground, but that it is not yet active.
- **applicationWillTerminate:** —Lets you know that your app is being terminated. This method is not called if your app is suspended.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and details.

Comment: @EARashel welcome, you can upvote if found ans is informative :)