# Got frame=ZERO in viewDidAppear with autoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have GPU renderer view need to be initialized based on the frame of a subview. But I always get frame=zero no matter where I put the code.

I can't put it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, because it will be called multiple times, I don't know which one is the correct one.

`viewDidAppear` also not the correct answer.

And I found that first `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will be called after `viewDidAppear`. `viewDidAppear` should be called when its subviews are **correctly** layout?

Comment: just write your code in viewwillappear() your problem will be solve try it

Comment: Why viewWillAppear will work even when viewDidAppear don't work? Just tested. @HimanshuMoradiya

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle refer this answer for your question\