# Is good to call selector method ViewWillAppear in NSNotificationCenter

Tags: objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I want to know is it good to call `viewWillAppear:` method in NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(viewWillAppear:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

Or

```
-(void)setUpInitialization{
// dump code here in ViewWillAppears.
}
```

Call the method setUpInitialization

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(setUpInitialization) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

If directly call `viewWillAppear` is a not good way to implement?

Comment: Isn't `viewWillAppear:` already called, by the system, when the app becomes active?

Comment: @mattsson Yes app become active for tabbarcontroller.

Comment: Then why call it again using the notification?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend calling directly `viewWillAppear` - first it breaks view lifecycle hierarchy calls, second if someone subclasses from your class he may have hard time debugging he's own class, because `viewWillAppear` will be called more frequently than usual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NO**.

1. `viewWillAppear` is a [template method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/template_pattern.htm), the OS will call it for you, you should never call it manually by your self.
2. Before the view would disappear, calling `viewWillAppear` is being called twice in a `UIViewController`'s [lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570363/3327210)  would break the hierarchy, it could result to some very strange behaviour.
3. Debugging your own `UIViewController` subclasses, or any subclasses will be a nightmare.

As you are suggesting, do the second option using `setUpInitialization()` function, and do everything there, when you receive the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`.