# How to run loops?

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

var FamilyOne = ["Sarah", "Female", "Granddaughter"]
var FamilyTwo = ["Isabel", "Female", "Granddaughter"]
var FamilyThree = ["Maya", "Female", "Granddaughter"]
var FamilyFour = ["Jean", "Female", "Daughter"]
var FamilyFive = ["Jennie", "Female", "Daughter"]

var MainArray = FamilyOne

var FemaleArray = ["Ava", "Mary", "Ann", "Carolina", "Jessica", "Emily",     "Elizabeth"]
var Photo = MainArray[0]
var SImage = UIImage(named: Photo)

var Gender = MainArray[1]
var Relation = MainArray[2]

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
    UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var ButtonOne: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var BUttonTwo: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var ButtonThree: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var BUtton4: UIButton!

    var SimageView = UIImageView(image: SImage!)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        label.text = ("What is the name of your \(Relation) ?")

        SimageView.frame = CGRect(x: 67, y: 40, width: 240, height: 128)
        view.addSubview(SimageView)

        ButtonOne.setTitle(FemaleArray[4], for: UIControlState.normal)
        BUttonTwo.setTitle(MainArray[0], for: UIControlState.normal)
        ButtonThree.setTitle(FemaleArray[5], for: UIControlState.normal)
        BUtton4.setTitle(FemaleArray[2], for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
}
```

How can I put this code into a for loop and have it change "MainArray"'s value to FamilyTwo the second time the loop runs, FamilyThree the third time the loop runs, ect. ect.? When I put a for loop before the ViewController I constantly get the error 'Expression not allowed on top level'.

Comment: if each array is meant to represent a family member, then it might be better to create a custom class to represent each one. You could name it something like FamilyMember and give it string properties like name, gender, and relation.

Comment: How I understand, put it/call it in `viewDidLoad()`. If you are not familiar with a viewControllers life cycle, [check it out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12608364/1457385).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if you simply want to change the value of your `MainArray` in runtime with the set of families you can store them in a new collection.

```
var FamilyOne = ["Sarah", "Female", "Granddaughter"]
var FamilyTwo = ["Isabel", "Female", "Granddaughter"]
var FamilyThree = ["Maya", "Female", "Granddaughter"]
var FamilyFour = ["Jean", "Female", "Daughter"]
var FamilyFive = ["Jennie", "Female", "Daughter"]
let Families = [FamilyOne, FamilyTwo, FamilyThree, FamilyFour, FamilyFive]

var MainArray = FamilyOne //set initial value?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //loop here
    for family in Families{
       MainArray = family
    }
}
```

`Expression not allowed on top level` is normal if you write the loop outside a function or a class.