# Where to remove delegate in app life cycle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I've an instance of a class, which its delegate can only called once.

A view controller (View A) will call `self.delegate = self`, and has buttons to go to other view controller (VC).

In one of the VC, I **need** to call this instance and set the delegate again.

Initially I set the delegate in `viewWillAppear` but that won't work, because I'm loading the delegate data in `viewDidLoad`, and since `viewDidLoad` will run first, I can either set delegate in `viewDidLoad` or `loadView`.

Whereas removing delegate can be in `dealloc`, or `viewWillDisappear`, but if I'm presenting a VC, `dealloc` of View A won't be called isn't it? As the view is not removed yet.

So my question is, where to I set `self.delegate = nil` in view A?

If I'm using present VC method, where should I set and remove the delegate in View A?
While in presented VC, I can just set and remove via `viewDidLoad` and `dealloc`.

Asking this in terms of best practice for app life cycle.

I've viewed [iOS uiviewcontroller life cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I should have test this myself before asking.

Anyway, for others who might be interested to know as well.

View A will dealloc when going to other viewController (View B). So it is safe to remove delegate at View A's dealloc, and set the delegate at View B.

Where as if View B is presented by clicking on a in View A, dealloc won't be called. So in this case, it'll be better to use viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear for setting and removing delegate respectively.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You have to setDelegate to self in viewDidAppear and set Delegate to nil in viewDidDisappear