# UISegmented Control Disappears After Dismissing View

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

In working on this app with a TabBar at the bottom, NavBar at the top with a Segmented Control:

I have an issue where the View A (Segment One) with a UITableView, upon selecting a cell and displaying a new view with more details, when I click back, the Segmented control at the top will disappear and the TableView from View A will be pushed up.

This doesn't always happen - sometimes after many tries or sometimes just one. I haven't found any correlation to what's causing it.

I have found that if I select View B from the segmented Control, then back to View A, then click on one of the table cells to get to the details screen and then click back, 100% of the time the Top Nav Bar disappears with the segmented control.

[image]

**TabBarItemOneViewController**

```
let segmentOneVC: SegmentOneViewController
let segmentTwoVC: SegmentTwoViewController

var currentViewController: UIViewController

let viewControllerYLoc = 60 // statusBarHeight + topBarHeight
let viewWidth = Helper.getViewWidth()
let tabBarHeight = 40

func pressedSegItem(segControl: UISegmentedControl){

    let viewControllerHeight = Int(self.view.frame.height)

    let viewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: viewControllerYLoc, width: Int(viewWidth), height: viewControllerHeight)

    let selectedIndex = segControl.selectedSegmentIndex
    previouslySelectedMyLoadsIndex = selectedIndex

    self.currentViewController.removeFromParentViewController()

    if(selectedIndex == 0){
        currentViewController = segmentOneVC
    }
    else if(selectedIndex == 1){
        currentViewController = segmentTwoVC
    }

    self.view.addSubview(self.currentViewController.view)
    self.currentViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}

public init() {

    segmentOneVC = SegmentOneViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    segmentTwoVC = SegmentTwoViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

    if(previouslySelectedIndex == 0){
        currentViewController = segmentOneVC
    }
    else{
        currentViewController = segmentTwoVC
    }

    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

    self.calculateItems()

    self.addSegmentedControl()

    let viewControllerHeight = (Int(self.view.frame.height) - viewControllerYLoc) - tabBarHeight

    let viewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: viewControllerYLoc, width: Int(viewWidth), height: viewControllerHeight)

    self.currentViewController.view.frame = viewFrame
    self.addChildViewController(segmentOneVC)
    self.addChildViewController(segmentTwoVC)
    self.view.addSubview(self.currentViewController.view)
    self.currentViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

**SegmentOneViewController** (note: SegmentTwoViewController is identical)

```
let cellReuseIdentifier = "ItemDetailTableViewCell"

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let row = indexPath.row

    let dataItem = self.dataArray[row]

    let itemDetailVC = ItemDetailViewController()
    itemDetailVC.dataItem = dataItem
    self.present(itemDetailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func addTableView(){
    self.tableView = UITableView()

    tableView.register(ItemDetailTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: self.cellReuseIdentifier)

    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Int(viewWidth), height: (Int(self.view.frame.height) - bottomOfTopNavBar) - heightOfTabBar)

    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    loadData()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    addTableView()
}
```

**ItemDetailViewController**

```
// Connected to a back button in a top Navigation Bar
func goBack(){
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Seems rather difficult to guess without seeing any source code.

Comment: I'll edit with some code samples.

Comment: Is your detail view presented modally?

Comment: Are you building the view in IB / storyboard or in code?

Comment: @andrewbuilder I'm doing it all with code.

Comment: The problem you're facing is to do with how you instantiate the view objects and when you do this in the view controller lifecycle. I'll read through your sample code, think on this and prepare a proper answer.

Comment: @andrewbuilder Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice graphics BTW... that illustration make it much easier to understand your problem.

Also BTW, I'm an Obj-C person, still learning the nuances of Swift, so please let me know if my syntax or otherwise is incorrect. I'm also relatively inexperienced in using container VC's.

​
I've written my response in two parts.

The First Part is my attempt to solve your problem.

The Second Part is my suggestion for an alternative for you to consider.

**First Part**

This is my understanding of the order/sequence of execution in your code...

*Parent View with Segmented Control*

1. `public init ()` : on instantiation of the parent view controller, two child VCs (segmentOneVC and segmentTwoVC) are instantiated and depending on previous selection are assigned as `currentViewController`. Then you add a segmented control to the `TabBarItemOneViewController`.
2. User taps a segmented control.
3. Depending on user input, either the `SegmentOneViewController` or `SegmentTwoViewController` view is added as a `subview` to the `TabBarItemOneViewController.view`. (Note that this is also done when the VC is initialised.)

*Child View*

4. `override func viewDidLoad()` : once the view did load, you call the function `addTableView`.
5. `func addTableView()` : in this custom function you instantiate your table view and place it within the SegmentOneViewController, which is itself I assume a `UIViewController`.
6. `override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)` : you call the custom function `loadData` and set your table view data source and delegate.

*Back Button*

7. User taps the back button.
8. Child VC is dismissed and the `TabBarItemOneViewController` becomes the active view on screen.

Let's look at what does not happen in the view controller lifecycle when the back button is pressed... Item 1 in the list.

This may explain the inconsistency.

Try this... run the app, tap the tab control to take you to `TabBarItemOneViewController`. Don't tap the segmented control. Tap a line in your table view. Tap the back button in your child VC. I'd take a guess your segmented control is still there.

Now try this... run the app, tap the tab control to take you to `TabBarItemOneViewController`. Tap the segmented control. Tap a line in your table view. Tap the back button in your child VC. I'd take a guess your segmented control is no longer there.

Why? Because the custom function `pressedSegItem` that I assume has a target action assigned to the segmented control, will overwrite your `init`, which is where you add the segmented control into the tab bar view controller.

So by way of example, try placing the code to instantiate your segmented control instead in an override function of `viewWillAppear` of the `TabBarItemOneViewController` VC.

So a couple of concepts to think about...

- lazy loading to save memory allocation - only instantiate the objects you need when the user specifically requests that function in the app;
- order of execution of each function in the `UIViewController` lifecycle; and
- which functions are executed once and which are executed each time your view becomes first responder / the active view.

Some reading recomendations:

- This [SO question titled :Looking to understand the iOS UIViewController lifecycle"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle) presents a lot of good information, but understand that some of the information is incorrect due to deprecation of `viewDidUnload` from iOS 6.
- Which is why you should always go to the [Apple documentation for UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller) to refer to the latest API reference.

**Second Part**

By providing this alternative, I'm not suggesting that your approach is incorrect, however I am suggesting an alternative for you to consider.

I've always used tab bar controllers to change views and segmented controls to filter data sets or change the appearance of the current view.

Think about using a `UISegmentedControl` to manage or adjust the data set within only one table view. This will alleviate the need for multiple view controllers and the juggling act of managing these.

For example, when writing your data source and delegate methods / functions for your tabel view, you can include the following code to ensure the table view loads and responds accordinagly:

```
let selectedIndex = segControl.selectedSegmentIndex
if(selectedIndex == 0) {
    rowHeight = 20 'for example
} else {
    rowHeight = 30 'for example
}
```

Then you'd need to relaod your table view to effect the changes.

Comment: I actually really liked this alternative a lot more. I ended up refactoring the entire section of the app since both screens were just table view cells. I could see going with my approach if the two screens are drastically different.