# What is viewDidLoad() for?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Can someone please help me understand what exactly viewDidLoad()does? I know it's called when the view controller is first loaded into memory. I addition, I am aware I can treat it as a main(). But I would like to know more about it. What does it reference too? UIView? It loads and treats all the buttons, labels, etc? Having a detailed and well explained overview would help!

In addition, I'm also confused about override. Does it add code to existent viewDidLoad()?

Thank you!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

P.S I am new here, feel free to leave any comments about my question formatting.

Comment: I think this is a good anwser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

viewDidLoad is the method that is called once the MainView of a ViewController has been loaded. This is called after loadView is called.[In the image you can see the MainView and other views within it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CL9jr.png). As soon as MainView has been loaded whatever will be included within the MainView you can get access to it (YES, all the buttons, labels, etc) in the ViewDidLoad method.

*I'm also confused about override. Does it add code to existent viewDidLoad()?*

As we know **if subclass provides the specific implementation of the method that has been provided by one of its parent class, it is known as method overriding.**

Here, the viewDidLoad in the superclass (UIViewController) is only an empty function. You need to Just override the function for your initial setup of the view once it has been loaded.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` is called when the `ViewController` has loaded its view hierarchy into memory. This is the point where you can perform your customized initialisation for your view controller.

For instance, if your view controller has a `UILabel` and you want to set a custom text to it, this is the point where you do that.