# Adding Constraints to ViewController with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, constraints

I want to add **container** view to the main view (**rootViewController.view**), but the following gives exception. I know it about the **constraints** but not able to find out why.

```
import UIKit

class rootViewController : UIViewController {

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        setupLoginView()
    }

    func setupLoginView() {

        // User ID label
        let userIDLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
        userIDLabel.text = "User ID"

        // Password label
        let passwordLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
        passwordLabel.text = "Password"

        // User ID text
        let userIDText:UITextField = UITextField()

        // Password text
        let passwordText:UITextField = UITextField()

        // Login button
        let loginBtn:UIButton = UIButton()
        loginBtn.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)

        // Container view
        let container:UIView = UIView()

        container.addSubview(userIDLabel)
        container.addSubview(userIDText)
        container.addSubview(passwordLabel)
        container.addSubview(passwordText)
        container.addSubview(loginBtn)

        view.addSubview(container)

        // Add constraints
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: container, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 300)
        let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: container, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200)
        let centerXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: container, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let centerYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: container, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        container.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
        container.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
        container.addConstraint(centerXConstraint)
        container.addConstraint(centerYConstraint)

    }

}
```

Gives the following exception, with hint **"Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal"**

> 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view. 
>   Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of
>   the view?  That's illegal. constraint: NSLayoutConstraint:0x170089830
>   UIView:0x12de138c0.centerX == UIView:0x12de0e650.centerX   (active)>

Comment: try giving `frame`/Layout to each of your items like userIDLabel, passwordLabel etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code for adding the center constraints with these lines:

```
view.addConstraint(centerXConstraint)
view.addConstraint(centerYConstraint)
```

You can't add a constaint on the `container` with a reference to it's superview.

And move the `setupLoginView()` to `viewDidLoad` instead of `init()`.

Don't forget to remove the warning in the console to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` for all the created views (container, labels, buttons and textviews).

Answer (score 1):

**1. Move `setupLoginView()` to `viewDidLoad()`**

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupLoginView()
}
```

**2. Set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` of `container`**

```
    container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

**3. Add `constraints` to relevant `views`:**

```
    container.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
    container.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
    view.addConstraint(centerXConstraint)
    view.addConstraint(centerYConstraint)
```

Answer (score 0):

The ViewController's view does not exist yet. Move the `setupLoginView()` call from the `init()` method to `viewDidLoad()`.

Also - as @Pranav Kasetti suggests - you have to add the center constraints to the `view` instead of the `container`.

Last but not least set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` for all the created views (including the `container`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you define properties in the init method, but it's not the good entry point for a `ViewController`. You should [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle) for some details.

Then, replace

```
init() {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
```

by this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
```

and it should works.