# navigationItem title is not changing

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to change the title of the page when I get `group` data from parent view in 3 ways but it didn't change the title

```
var group : Group? {
    didSet{
        self.navigationItem.title = "from code"
        self.navigationController?.navigationItem.title = "from code"
        self.title = "from code"
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do it in `didSet`. Rather set the title in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @Adeel placing it in viewDidLoad fixed it, but I am wondering why!?

Comment: I'll explain it in the answer.

Comment: @Adeel great! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are probably setting the title before the view of the view controller is instantiated. That's why it isn't changing. You must do view related stuff within or after `viewDidLoad` method of the view controller. For a better understanding of the life cycle of `UIViewController` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle) thread.

Comment: The `navigationItem` has nothing to do with `UIViewController.view` and it is often needed before the `view` is used.

Comment: @Sulthan so what do you think is the problem?

Comment: @dotfreelancer Hard to say without seeing the actual code.

Comment: nothing there except the attached code + viewDidLoad func. that's why i think the @Adeel answer is reasonable!

Comment: I'm also wondering why you can't set the title of the view controller inside the didSet method. view of the view controller gets instantiated 'before' the didSet method is called so I think this answer is not to be taken seriously.