# Xcode Swift ViewDidLoad

Tags: swift, xcode, viewdidload

I have two ViewControllers. When I press a button on the FirstViewController the SecondViewController shows up. When I press a button on the SecondViewController the FirstViewController shows up again. The problem is, that the View on the FirstViewController does not load again. The ViewDidLoad loop does not load again.
I want to create a loop, which checks a variable every single time the FirstViewController shows up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking to understand the iOS UIViewController lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle)

Comment: maybe the `-viewWillAppear(_:)` is your desired scope; if you are interested more about the life-cycle of the view controllers (__you are!__), please spend time on reading the [Apple docs about it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put that code in [`viewDidAppear`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621423-viewdidappear) or [`viewWillAppear`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear).

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLoad` is only called when the view first loads. Sounds like you are looking for the `viewDidAppear` (or `viewWillAppear`) method which is called every time view has just been (`viewDidAppear`) or is about to appear (`viewWillAppear`).

So you're probably looking for either of those methods. You might want to look at the diagram on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller) for more information

Answer (score 0):

**ViewDidLoad** method call when you add an instance of `UIViewController` into `Navgation Stack`.

**I assumed you already know about `Navigation Stack`.**

When you display `FirstViewController` from `SecondViewController` it means you did one thing from two possible ways

**1.** You `SecondViewController` from `Navigation Stack` in this way `ViewDidLoad` of `FirstViewController` will never call because `FirstViewController` already loaded in the memory. In this case `ViewDidAppear` and `ViewWillAppear` will execute. Because these methods will always call whenever view is going to appear on screen.

**2.** You created another instance of `FirstViewController` on `SecondViewController` and push `FirstViewController`'s instance on `Navigation Stack`. In this way a new instance of `FirstViewController` will be added and `ViewDidLoad` will automatically called. And a looped of `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController` will automatically created.

Hopefully you understand now why `ViewDidLoad` method never called for you.