# How to set constraints for custom subclass of UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I built a custom view as a subclass of UIView. Now, I'd like to set the constraints for this view in my ViewController instead of setting the frame. This is the custom view class:

#### PullUpView.swift

```
//
//  PullUpView.swift
//  
//

import UIKit

final internal class PullUpView: UIView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    // MARK: - Variables
    private var animator                : UIDynamicAnimator!
    private var collisionBehavior       : UICollisionBehavior!
    private var snapBehaviour           : UISnapBehavior?
    private var dynamicItemBehavior     : UIDynamicItemBehavior!
    private var gravityBehavior         : UIGravityBehavior!
    private var panGestureRecognizer    : UIPanGestureRecognizer!
    internal var delegate               : PullUpViewDelegate?


    // MARK: - Setup the view when bounds are defined.
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            print(self.frame)
            print(self.bounds)
            setupStyle()
            setupBehavior()
            setupPanGesture()
        }
    }

    override var frame: CGRect {
        didSet {
            print(self.frame)
            print(self.bounds)
            setupStyle()
            setupBehavior()
            setupPanGesture()
        }
    }
}


// MARK: - Behavior (Collision, Gravity, etc.)
private extension PullUpView {
    final private func setupBehavior() {
        guard let superview = superview else { return }
        animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: superview)
        dynamicItemBehavior = UIDynamicItemBehavior(items: [self])
        dynamicItemBehavior.allowsRotation = false
        dynamicItemBehavior.elasticity = 0

        gravityBehavior = UIGravityBehavior(items: [self])
        gravityBehavior.gravityDirection = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 1)

        collisionBehavior = UICollisionBehavior(items: [self])

        configureContainer()

        animator.addBehavior(gravityBehavior)
        animator.addBehavior(dynamicItemBehavior)
        animator.addBehavior(collisionBehavior)
    }

    final private func configureContainer() {
        let boundaryWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let boundaryHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

        collisionBehavior.addBoundary(withIdentifier: "upper" as NSCopying, from: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), to: CGPoint(x: boundaryWidth, y: 0))

        collisionBehavior.addBoundary(withIdentifier: "lower" as NSCopying, from: CGPoint(x: 0, y: boundaryHeight + self.frame.height - 66), to: CGPoint(x: boundaryWidth, y: boundaryHeight + self.frame.height - 66))
    }

    final private func snapToBottom() {
        gravityBehavior.gravityDirection = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 2.5)
    }

    final private func snapToTop() {
        gravityBehavior.gravityDirection = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -2.5)
    }
}


// MARK: - Style (Corner-radius, background, etc.)
private extension PullUpView {
    final private func setupStyle() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0)
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .regular)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = self.bounds
        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.addSubview(blurEffectView)

        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let dragBar = UIView()
        dragBar.backgroundColor = .gray
        dragBar.frame = CGRect(x: (self.bounds.width / 2) - 5, y: self.bounds.origin.y + 5, width: 10, height: 2)
        self.addSubview(dragBar)
    }
}



// MARK: - Pan Gesture Recognizer and Handler Functions
internal extension PullUpView {
    final private func setupPanGesture() {
        panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture(_:)))
        panGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
    }

    @objc final private func handlePanGesture(_ panGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let superview = superview else { return }
        if let viewCanMove: Bool = delegate?.viewCanMove?(pullUpView: self) {
            if !viewCanMove {
                return
            }
        }

        let velocity = panGestureRecognizer.velocity(in: superview).y

        var movement = self.frame
        movement.origin.x = 0
        movement.origin.y = movement.origin.y + (velocity * 0.05)

        if panGestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
            panGestureEnded()
        } else if panGestureRecognizer.state == .began {
            snapToBottom()
        } else {
            animator.removeBehavior(snapBehaviour ?? UIPushBehavior())
            snapBehaviour = UISnapBehavior(item: self, snapTo: CGPoint(x: movement.midX, y: movement.midY))
            animator.addBehavior(snapBehaviour ?? UIPushBehavior())
        }
    }

    final private func panGestureEnded() {
        animator.removeBehavior(snapBehaviour ?? UIPushBehavior())

        let velocity = dynamicItemBehavior.linearVelocity(for: self)

        if fabsf(Float(velocity.y)) > 250 {
            if velocity.y < 0 {
                moveViewIfPossible(direction: .up)
            } else {
                moveViewIfPossible(direction: .down)
            }
        } else {
            if let superviewHeight = self.superview?.bounds.size.height {
                // User scrolled over half of the screen...
                if self.frame.origin.y > superviewHeight / 2 {
                    moveViewIfPossible(direction: .down)
                } else {
                    moveViewIfPossible(direction: .up)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    final private func moveViewIfPossible(direction: PullUpViewPanDirection) {
        if let viewCanMove: Bool = delegate?.viewCanSnap?(pullUpView: self, direction: direction) {
            if viewCanMove {
                delegate?.viewWillMove?(pullUpView: self, direction: direction)
                direction == .up ? snapToTop() : snapToBottom()
            }
        } else {
            delegate?.viewWillMove?(pullUpView: self, direction: direction)
            direction == .up ? snapToTop() : snapToBottom()
        }
    }
}


// MARK: - PullUpViewPanDirection declared inside
internal extension PullUpView {
    /// An enum that defines whether the view moves up or down.
    @objc
    internal enum PullUpViewPanDirection: Int {
        case
        up,
        down
    }
}
```

But when I set the constraints, I always get a frame with a negative origin:

#### ViewController.swift

```
pullUpView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
pullUpView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
pullUpView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
pullUpView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
pullUpView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

**Frame**: 
(**-160.0**, **-252.0**, 320.0, 504.0)

**Bounds**:
(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 504.0)

What is strange is that if I comment out the function *setupBehavior()*, the view is displayed correctly (but it will fail as soon as the pan gesture handler is triggered).

*Instead, if I set the **frame**:*

```
pullUpView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.height - 66, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
```

it works fine.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: I think your first mistake is thinking about *frames* when using auto layout. Simply put, they don't work together. Second, just *use* the view life cycle - not *abuse* it. It may appear like solid logic to `override` bounds and frames, but why? If you want to use constraints just accept that the OS will do it's thing. Set your constraints in `viewDidLoad` without worrying about bounds and frames... accept that by time `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` things will be there. Overriding `didSet` on bounds and frames? Totally wrong things to do when using auto layout.

Comment: @dfd But how and where would I call the setup***() functions if I wouldn't override the frame or bounds? Could you possibly write an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "setup***() functions". I'll give you an example as an answer - the markdown may help - if the answer isn't helpful, let me know I'll delete it.

Comment: Thank you! I was talking about setupStyle(), setupBehavior() and setupPanGesture(). They are called within didSet().

Comment: I focused on "constraints" because of your question title. But from what I see I think most everything could simply be done in `viewDidLoad` because you really want to do these things *once* and not multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your constraints you are trying to set, it appears you want a view controller - let's call it `MainViewController` - to have a custom view as it's full screen view.

The first thing you should do when using auto layout is *forget* about frames. In most cases, *forget* about bounds. Next, I'd [use the view life cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle#12608364) and forget about using `didSet` on bounds and frames. Here's how I'd do it:

Set everything you possibly can in `viewDidLoad` - and in your case, it's everything:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pullUpView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(pullUpView)

    pullUpView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    pullUpView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    pullUpView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    pullUpView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

That's about it! Relevant notes:

- You properly set the auto resizing mask to `false`. Good job. If you don't you'll get constraint conflict. More importantly, if you **do** you've basically have no need to worry about bounds or frames.
- The auto resizing mask is automatically set to false if you use IB.
- If you use anchors and wish to make your custom view have either (a) a 10 point border or (b) be 50% width/height, use a `constant: 10` or a `multiplier: 0.5`.
- Not required, but it helps keep away from view controller size - move your constraints into it's own subroutine (I call mine `setUpConstraints()` and make it an `extension` to your view controller.

Last point, and from what I gleaned from an email from Apple iTunesConnect is going to be demanded come April, use the "safe area" for all your devices. Here's what I do:

```
let safeAreaView = UIView()

safeAreaView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(safeAreaView)

if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    safeAreaView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(guide.topAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
    safeAreaView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(guide.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
} else {
    safeAreaView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    safeAreaView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
}
safeAreaView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
safeAreaView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

There are other ways to do this (this creates a `UIView`) but now you set all your constraints against `safeAreaView` instead of `self.view`.

Final note: if you *must* reference a frame, do it as late as possible in the view controller view life-cycle, say `viewDidLayoutSubview`. While the *bounds* may be known as early as `viewDidLoad`, *frames* aren't.

I'll bet that if you traced how many time the frame `didSet` was happening on your average view load or orientation change, you'll find it more than you thought.