# Unable to redirect to the authentication page using Xamarin.OAuth 2.0

Tags: ios, xamarin, oauth-2.0, xamarin.ios, native

Currently I am using the Xamarin forms for creating the Android and iOS. Now I am using the OAuth2.0 for login functionality. So I have created one view controller in Xamarin iOS project. In the AppDelegate class, I am calling my controller view from the FinishedLaunching method.

Like:

```
var mainController = new ViewController(); // Your view controller here
 mainController.ViewDidLoad();
```

in the ViewDidLoad write the logic of the OAuth2.0 and used the 
`this.PresentViewController(authGui, true, null)`. But in my project it is not redirecting to page and give the below warning

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x7fde4a9d6800> on
<ViewController: 0x7fde4a53f9d0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: This post needed significant reformatting, and was largely unreadable in its first iteration. It's a bit better now I have edited it. Please make an effort to learn the formatting tools here, and supply your questions in a readable form the first time around, to reduce volunteer editor workload.

Comment: I will take care of it next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to trigger `ViewDidLoad()` event manually. We assume you use the blank app template. You should set the `Window`'s `RootViewController` to show it, then the `ViewDidLoad()` event will fire. Please read [this documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController/) about iOS UIViewController for more details, also refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570363/8354952) about UIViewController's lifecycle.

After you have brought this `mainController` into Window, you can use `this.PresentViewController(authGui, true, null)` to present the **OAuth view** on the screen.

[Authenticating Users with an Identity Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth) tells you how to implement **OAuth** on each platform, you should read it more carefully. Besides on iOS if you want to redirect back to your app, set a custom **URL scheme** in `Info.plist`. When it comes back, the event `OpenUrl()` will be called, override it in the `AppDelegate.cs`.