# Can't get UIVew sizes

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints

I add UIViews dynamically in code. There are a lot of views I want to add. Here is one for example:

```
let typeImage = UIImageView()
typeImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
rootView.addSubview(typeImage)
typeImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28).isActive = true
typeImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28).isActive = true
typeImage.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rootView.leftAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
typeImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rootView.topAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
typeImage.backgroundColor = gh.myRed
typeImage.image = UIImage(named: "ic_question_bej")
```

I want to count sum of all elements that I add and finally set this counted value to my root view height. The problem is that

```
typeImage.frame.size.height
typeImage.bounds.size.height
```

always return 0.0

So how can I get height in CGFloat of newly added UIView via code?
Maybe I should set height of rootview to wrap all my subview in another way?

**Edit**

Xcode loads view with some delay and if you will try to get view size immediately after adding it to parent you will get 0.0 sizes.

You have to call `yourCustomView.layoutIfNeeded()` before cheking sizes.

Thanks Chenjtc for right Answer.

Comment: Unrelated but it's easier to create the image view as `let typeImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "ic_question_bej"))`.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is you are checking frame sizes too soon - try `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Maybe - maybe `viewWillLayoutSubviews` but **certainly** not `viewDidLoad`! (If you are doing this, I'd suggest checking this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle ) One more thing that may help - since it seems you already know the height of each `typeImage` -  if to "track" how many you've created. Arrays have a `count` property that is "1" based. Also,you could use a tag property that may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the code like this:
`typeImage.layoutIfNeeded()`
before the code :
`typeImage.frame.size.height
typeImage.bounds.size.height`

constraint will not layout immediately, you should use `layoutIfNeeded` to layout the view, then you can get th frame

Comment: after 6 hours of searching you finally answered my question!!! Yes after calling layoutIfNeeded() all works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the sum of multiple views height in CGFloat you can do it like this :

```
let viewHeight = self.view.frame.height  //this in CGFloat
let sumHeight = viewHeight + ... other UIViews
print(sumHeight) // 568.0 for iPhone SE
```

or if you want to set your new UIView height you can do it by changing :

```
typeImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28).isActive = true
```

//

To :

```
typeImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
```

Comment: can i get height in float of a view that i add dynamically? For example i add 5 buttons with height of 25 CGFloat. And finally i want there rootView height to be button.height * 5. The problem is that button.frame.size always 0.0

Comment: You can change (multiplier = 0.75) to take %75 of the view

Comment: Check my updated answer up .. if you want the height in CGFloat like this : 'view.frame.height'

Comment: Please mark my answer as the right one as it satisfy your posted question .

Comment: yes view.frame.height returns me height of my full screen. When i do myCustomRightNowAddedView.frame.height it returns 0.0 . Why it returns 0 , when i set it height to 28?