# Keyboard didn't show with becomeFirstResponder()

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

I created a text field in iOS and I want the keyboard to pop out every time I open it. I tried the following code in .swift file:

```
@IBOutlet weak var messageTextview: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.messageTextview.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

However, the keyboard didn't show. Can someone please help me with it?

Comment: Since `viewDidLoad` is called before the view is presented on the screen, it's likely that the OS has simply, ignored your request, as it's not possible for the field to become the first responder.  Instead, maybe use `viewDidAppear` instead

Comment: Are you using a simulator or device?

Comment: I'm using a simulator

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sorry, I don't quite understand want you mean, do you mean I should make a new function called viewDidAppear, and put self.messageTextview.becomeFirstResponder() inside it? Thank you!

Comment: @ZHENBIAN Yes. Perhaps you should have a look at [Understand the View Controller Lifecycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html) and [Looking to understand the iOS UIViewController lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle) to gain a better understand of the lifecycle of a `UIViewController`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you! and I add                                                        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
                                                
        self.messageTextview.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a simulator and keyboard does not show on that then press ⇧+⌘+K

Comment: It works, Thank you very much!