# Lifecycle awareness in iOS, Swift, Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, swift, xamarin

I am currently working on a xamarin cross-platform application and need to add reusable lifecycle-aware functionality in multiple classes, which do not have common ancestors within their class hierarchy. I thought about lifecycle aware components I know from android development, but it seems to be that such a functionality does not exist for iOs development. Am I wrong in this regard? Is there a better way of doing so?

Comment: Expose and hook into either the UIViewController and/or the AppDelegate lifecycle methods  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45797285/4984832 : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html

Comment: For those, who come up with a similar question, I have created a project transferring the behavior of the android jetpack lifecycle SDK to iOs ViewControllers: https://github.com/gourmet9000/ios_lifecycle_awareness