# Why doesn't code in (isMovingToParentViewController) run in viewDidLayoutSubviews()

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, viewdidlayoutsubviews

I have a viewController, I'm using anchors and I want to get the frame of a button. I only want the frame when the view is pushed on so I use `isMovingToParentViewController`. Like this:

```
if isMovingToParentViewController {

    let myButtonFrame = myButton.convert(myButton.bounds, to: self.view)
}
```

When I add it in `viewWillAppear` the code to get the button's frame runs but when I add the same code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` it doesn't run.

**Why is that?**

Just to be clear in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` when I add a break point it does hit `if isMovingToParentViewController` but the code **inside** of it never gets hit.

When the view gets pushed on isMovingToParentViewController **does** get hit, when it pops isMovingToParentViewController **doesn't** get hit.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // anchors are set here but the frames haven't been set yet
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if isMovingToParentViewController {

        // this code runs
        let myButtonFrame = myButton.convert(myButton.bounds, to: self.view)
    }
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if isMovingToParentViewController {

        // this code NEVER runs
        let myButtonFrame = myButton.convert(myButton.bounds, to: self.view)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for checking `isMoving` flag? You can check `UIViewController` lifecycle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45797285/2395636)

Comment: @Kamran thanks for the link but the issue isn't a lifecycle issue, that's a different topic. The issue is why does the breakpoint hit it, but then skip what's inside of it?

Comment: If `isMovingToParentViewController` is `false` then how can it enter?

Comment: How is it false there when it's true in viewWillAppear? If you can explain why it's false there but true in viewWillAppear then that's the answer to the question.

Comment: Have you debugged the `UIViewController` lifecycle? This flag behaves according to the presentation modal of the `viewController`. You should know how this flag work when you push/pop a `viewController` or add/remove as a child `viewController`. Once you know all these behaviors then you will find that for this particular `viewController` this flag is true only in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` and for rest of the lifecycle methods, it is `false`.

Comment: When I pop it the flag doesn’t get hit but when I push it does. I didn’t know that it stays false for the other lifecycle methods, thanks for the info. I still don’t understand why it stays false though.

Answer (score 0):

The header documentation states that `isMovingToParentViewController` and the 3 other methods are only valid in appearance callbacks like `viewWillAppear` thus not in layout callbacks like `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

```
/*
  These four methods can be used in a view controller's appearance callbacks to determine if it is being
  presented, dismissed, or added or removed as a child view controller. For example, a view controller can
  check if it is disappearing because it was dismissed or popped by asking itself in its viewWillDisappear:
  method by checking the expression ([self isBeingDismissed] || [self isMovingFromParentViewController]).
*/

#if UIKIT_DEFINE_AS_PROPERTIES
@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isBeingPresented) BOOL beingPresented NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isBeingDismissed) BOOL beingDismissed NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);

@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isMovingToParentViewController) BOOL movingToParentViewController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isMovingFromParentViewController) BOOL movingFromParentViewController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
#else
- (BOOL)isBeingPresented NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
- (BOOL)isBeingDismissed NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);

- (BOOL)isMovingToParentViewController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
- (BOOL)isMovingFromParentViewController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
#endif
```