# How to implement TouchID with out any action. IOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id

I want to call API on touchId authentication on a particular screen not on buttonAction   or in ViewDidload.
Means if user  pressing the home button touchId  and if user is authorised it will Hit an API on a particular screen.

Comment: What about viewDidAppear?

Comment: sir, i  can't apply it on any ViewCycle.

Comment: Why not? You have to trigger the authentication somehow. You can *not* just have the user to touch the touchID sensor without calling the relevant API. The flow is: You call the API method, this shows the authentication UI, the user touches the touchID sensor, the API tells your app wether the user was able to authenticate or not.

Answer (score 0):

According to your case

> not on buttonAction or in ViewDidload.

You can use the `WillAppear` life cycle function, but beware every time the user enter that `UIViewController` the function will trigger, take a look on other life cycle function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5570363/8192960).

> Means if user pressing the home button touchId and if user is authorised it will Hit an API on a particular screen.

I suggest implementing the `TouchID` on the required scene.

Comment: sir i have an attendance module to mark attendance we have an API provided by backend  to mark attendance. we want that when user came to attendance screen he simply have to press TouchID on his device(homeScreen) and if user is authorised  the API will call and his attendance will be marked . They are also showing  previous record of attendance on the same screen so we can't implement  TouchID on any ViewCycle.

Comment: why you can't again ... how is showing something is preventing you from using viewCycle ?

Comment: because user don't have to give authentication to view anything on the same screen but only to  mark attendance .

Comment: .... use it in didload and go read about these cycle and why we use them