# iOS UIViewController life cycle callback similar to Android

Tags: ios

In Android there is the lifecycle callbacks for execute code in the onCreate, etc., lifecycle of an activity.

Does iOS have something similar like that?

I'm not asking about UIViewController lifecyycle. I want to know how to handle in one place all the viewdidappear, viewdidloaof, etc... of my view controllers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5562938/4063602

Comment: That does not answer my question. I think it's not duplicated by the link you indicate. My question is aimed at avoiding running the same code again and again in all UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the official documentation for this answer; here's official documentation of view controller lifecycle.

[UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller)