# width not picked up by cgrect()

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

i wanted to ask why doesnt my layer.frame = cgrect() doest not pick up the width (350) which i have set in the viewDidLayoutSubviews even though it does get printed in the console. but the width remains the same(390) as i have set in the storyboard.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

        width = masjidName.frame.width

        print(width)


    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        let bottomLine1 = CALayer()
        bottomLine1.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: masjidName.frame.height - 1, width: width, height: 1)
        bottomLine1.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        let bottomLine2 = CALayer()
        bottomLine2.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: masjidName.frame.height - 1, width: width, height: 1)
        bottomLine2.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

}
```

Comment: remove all constraints from the storyboard if you have any

Comment: that would ruin my design wouldnt it?

Comment: First, never, never, never call `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. If you comment-out your entire `viewDidLoad()` function, but leave `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` as you have it, what value do you get from from your current `print(width)` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by moving what I had In  viewdidload into  viewdidappear. As it takes a while for widths to update and viewdidload is called before it.

Answer (score 0):

Move your entire code to viewDidLayoutSubviews. 
viewDidLayoutSubviews is a callback method and you should not call this explicitly.
I would suggest you to go through ViewController lifecycle [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle)

Comment: i even tried it in the didset property of my variable. something is really strange here