# Calling a function from viewDidAppear() causes memory leak but from viewWillLayoutSubiews() not

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to understand why the same function causes a memory leak if I call it from viewDidAppear rather than viewWillLayoutSubiews.

I have two extensions that fits the sublayers of a view to its bounds:

```
extension CALayer {
    func fit(rect: CGRect) {
      frame = rect

      sublayers?.forEach { $0.fit(rect: rect) }
    }
}

extension UIView {
  func fitLayers() {
    layer.fit(rect: bounds)
  }
}
```

And the same call `priorityButton.fitLayers()` from viewDidAppear doesn't deallocate the Layer objects. Both do the job as expected and works well but I'd like to understand why is it.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess it's related to `UIViewController` lifecycle, when You call this function in `viewWillLayoutSubiews` it's OK because view will layout, but when called from `viewDidAppear`, all `UIViewController` layout methods called again because your function is layout stuff.
 `UIViewController` lifecycle explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32688124/5102722